# How to create a dictionary using a set of items as values from model

Tags: python, dictionary, django-models

I'm a newb at python and would appreciate some help please...

I have 2 models each with fields that i want to use as "values" for a dictionary i'm constructing. The 2nd class file is a sub table of the first one. And i want to pass the values from the models as item_sets.

```
class One(Models.model):

    id = models.Autofield(Primary_key=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

class Two(Models.model): 

    two_id = models.ForeignKey(One, blank=False)
    x_coord = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    y_coord = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    fontsize = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

From these 2 models i want to create a dictionary counting thru all the fields as a "set" and creating a dictionary subbing out the values from the models.

Eg:

```
def get_one_two(self, three)

one_two_three = One.objects.using("one_two").select_related("one_two_item_set").filter(three=three)
    one_count = 0
    for i in one_two_three:
        template_dict = {
            'id': one{id},
            'type': one{type},
            'name': one{name},
            'id': two{two_id},
            'x_coord': two{x_coord},
            'y_coord': two{y_coord},
            'fontsize': two{fontsize}
                    }
```

It doesn't seem to be working. Would appreciate some much needed assistance. I have to return the values from this to a main class in the end.

Thx

Comment: For the dict values, don't you mean: one.id, one.type, one.name, two.two_id??? The text "one{id}" doesn't look like valid python.

Comment: Oh I was trying to use the braces for substitution of values from the Model classes? It would work just using one.id and one.type etc.. ?

Comment: How did you intend on representing `One`s that have 0 or more than 1 `Two` associated with them?

Comment: Sorry, Ignacio, i'm not understanding your question. Can you please give me an example? Do you mean mean when I have variables that are named the same?